# Remember "repeat last change" on exit

Tags: vim

Vim's `.` (repeat last change) is a very useful feature.

Is there any way to remember the last change on exit (similar to how you can set up your vimrc and viminfo files to [remember the last file position](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_cursor_to_file_position_in_previous_editing_session) on exit)?

I'd like to be able to run Vim from the command line to open a file, hit `.`, and have Vim make the same change I just made to the last file I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But you can record your change in a register and play it back later:

```
qa              "start recording into register a
(do your thing)
q               " stop recording
@a              " play back the macro saved in register a
```

Or open your files from the same Vim session.

Comment: You can also use `@@` to playback the last repeat instead of doing `@a` over. It's handy if you have to do it more than once in the same session, I don't think it works across sessions though.

Comment: Yes, `@@` only works after an explicit `@a` so it won't help in another session.